# design pattern tools to use?

Tags: design-patterns

i have noticed that every area has some tools you can use to make things easier.

eg.

css = dreamweaver

doctrine/propel = orm designer // you dont have to hardcore code schemas manually and remembering all the syntax/variables

mysql = mysql workbench // the same

etc.

in this way you get aided and dont have to type things the hard way, and can learn the structure, but then use GUI tools to help you develop faster.

now i'm learning design patterns (singleton, factory, command, memento etc) and im wondering if there are some kind of tools you can use that will help you develop faster.

i dont know exactly what tools i'm trying to find, just helping me when coding with design patterns (schema drawings? references?)

are there any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a handful of pretty good UML tools that understand design patterns, and can generate the classes and relationships for you.  Many also have a "professional" version that will do the code generation (and also round trip) for you.  I can't vouch for any of them, as I have always gone with the standard version and drawn up the patterns by hand (although admittedly probably incorrectly most of the time).

Currently, my favorite UML tool is Visual Paradigm.  It's very nice because the standard version comes with the teamwork client, which allows you to merge models in SVN, whereas others (like MagicDraw) require you to pay over $1k for that functionality.